# wrong color when add facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

```
p = ggplot(pos.dat,
           aes(x = YY, y = lncpue,
               color = posterior(model2)[, 2])) +
  geom_point(position = "jitter") +
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'black', limits = c(0, 1))
```

The `x` variable is year, which contains 4 quarters and 5 regions. `color` is mapped to a continuous variable. The result of p is correct here, white white color for `y` values below -9:

[image]

When I add the following line, the colors change completely:

```
facet_grid(Region ~ Quarter)
```

[image]

Could anybody help me??

Comment: Don't refer to variables directly like in `color = posterior(model2)[, 2])`. This _sometimes_ works, but can fail, and always fails when facetting. Add a new column to your data.frame, e.g. `pos.dat$post <- posterior(model2)[, 2]`, then use `aes(x = YY, y = lncpue, color = post)`.

Comment: OMG!!!! It becomes correct:)))) Thank you sooooo much!